# Computer won't wake from hibernate

Tags: 10.04, boot, hibernate

So I have a pretty dumb problem...I accidentaly pressed Hibernate while trying to Restart...since then my computer wont boot into Ubuntu anymore (through normal mode or single user mode - rescue mode that is)...all I get is:

```
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys/ on root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or dirctory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= boot arg.

BusyBox v1.15.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.15.3-1ubuntu5) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Obviously I tried to fire up the Live CD and run fsck (or e2fsck) from there (or just try to do a Check of `/dev/sdb1`  my partition via gparted - which is basically the same thing). But it doesn't allow me...both gparted and fsck say that the device is busy (I can't even mount it in the LiveCD to rescue data)...umount /dev/sdb1 says its not mounted...any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to answer my own question, the Ubuntu Live CD's `e2fsck` won't work. So I booted up the [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php), ran `e2fsck`, now everything is back to normal.